# VBA ACCESS - ERROR 2465

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was trying to put this certain values to the table and am running into an issue.

**The code:**

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO FollowUpsDataBase(ER NUMBER, SUBJECT, FORWARDED TO, CASEHANDLER, [DUE DATE])" & " VALUES('" & [Me.cmdErNumber] & "','" & Me.cmdSubject & "','" & [Me.cboForwardedTo] & "','" & [Me.cboCasehandler] & "','" & [Me.cmdDueDate] & "')"
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: So this is the result.It actually worked and there is no more errors but still it won't insert the details at the table. Instead, it is inserted directly to the subform. Also, the combobox i used gives numbers instead of the strings i gave to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need square brackets  for form variables:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO FollowUpsDataBase([ER NUMBER], SUBJECT, [FORWARDED TO], CASEHANDLER, [DUE DATE])" & _
" VALUES('" & Me.cmdErNumber & "','" & Me.cmdSubject & "','" & Me.cboForwardedTo & "','" & Me.cboCasehandler & "','" & Me.cmdDueDate & "')"
```

Plus missing square brackets in SQL as per ClintB answer

Comment: So this is the result.It actually worked and there is no more errors but still it won't insert the details at the table. Instead, it is inserted directly to the subform. Also, the combobox i used gives numbers instead of the strings i gave to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have spaces in your field names you need to use [square brackets]

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO FollowUpsDataBase([ER NUMBER], SUBJECT, [FORWARDED TO], CASEHANDLER, [DUE DATE])" & " VALUES('" & Me.cmdErNumber & "','" & Me.cmdSubject & "','" & Me.cboForwardedTo & "','" & Me.cboCasehandler & "','" & Me.cmdDueDate & "')"
```

If its still not working you will need to post the error message.

Plus you have some square brackets around your form controls as per the above comment by Sergey S.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to wrap string expressions for date values correctly - and no quotes if ER NUMBER really is numeric:

```
CurrentDb.Execute _
"INSERT INTO FollowUpsDataBase([ER NUMBER], SUBJECT, [FORWARDED TO], CASEHANDLER, [DUE DATE]) " & _
"VALUES(" & Me!cmdErNumber.Value & ",'" & Me!cmdSubject.Value & "','" & Me!cboForwardedTo.Value & "','" & Me!cboCasehandler.Value & "',#" & Format(Me!cmdDueDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"
```

Comment: Just a note that adding .Value to certain types of controls can lead to issues. .Value is the default property so shouldn't be explicitly used, unless required.

Comment: Yes, it's a habit from _C#_ ... but it can't possibly cause any issues.